# Ajax Post refresh a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX and sending post.
in the response 200 Ok I can see that I am able to see the div I want. but that data is replaced but is getting appended.
can you please guide me how t debug these type of issues and fix them.

```
request.done(function(response) {
alert('Loaded.');
$('#data1').html(response);
});
```

I am able to see that "Loaded" alert is coming . so it is done.
on firebug I can see the 200 OK with the data.

1) #data1 is a Javascript template.
so, I am trying to update that template which will trigger the data in the tables and all to be modified.

data is :

```
<divid='data1'>
<script> ...................</script>
</div>
```

so I see that data getting updated . but the old data is not getting removed.
I tried : replaceWith
with that also , it is only appending the page and not replacing it

=

This Div is a Javascript template.
so this div as:

```
<div id='data1'><script> .....</script></div>
```

1. on my browser data is always getting updated and not replaced.
2. one more basic question , if I get response it is appending the data . when I see the viewsource, even the display shows example 20 entries . it shows only 10 entries which are initial , wit Ajax when a response is received will the source does not get modified?

Comment: Do you mean to use `.html(response)` instead of `.html(data)`?

Comment: the ´data´variable is just ´undefined´, use ´response´

Comment: thanks @Explosion ,sdespont its a typo. after doing that , I see on browser I can see the old entries and to that new entries are getting added. 1) page source did not change. when I say that div should the complete div not be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div=data1>
<script> ...................</script>
</div>
```

is not valid HTML. It should be:

```
<div id='data1'>
<script> ...................</script>
</div>
```

You're missing the `id=` part of the attribute.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. That is a typo in the question I have posted. I do have the attribute as mentioned. Issue is : on the browser the old table entries are not getting deleted which are in the div but the new entries are getting appended. that is the issue. I am re-phrasing the question. my mistake

Comment: Does the div in AJAX response really have the same ID as the div you're filling in? That's creating a duplicate ID, which could be causing problems. You end up with `<div id="data1"><div id="data1">...</div></div>`.

Comment: thank you @Barmar for the reply.yes AJAX response is having the same div ID as the filling. I dont see that as a duplicate.

Comment: I added more information in the question. please let me know if I am not clear

Comment: `$("#data1").html(data)` replaces the HTML inside the DIV, but it doesn't replace the DIV itself. So if `data` contains the same ID, you get a duplicate.

Comment: ,As you suggested I am sending from the server in response <script>...</script>. I have removed the div part. still I see that the data is getting appended and not replaced. should I do anything different if it is java script template and also I dont see that data is getting chnaged in page source

Comment: I'm not sure why the old content isn't being removed. Before it does anything with the new data, `html()` calls `empty()` to clear out the old data. I tried to reproduce your problem in a fiddle and couldn't.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it is, `$("#data1").html(data)` is equivalent to `$("#data1").empty().append(data)`. Can you make a fiddle to demonstrate the problem, it's getting impossible to do this just in text.

Comment: I will create fiddle and will let you know

Comment: while I am trying fiddle to keep only the impacted code,I have on emore question you said: As this is script <script>, .html and .append() will not be kept in DOM and onlt eval() is done. if that is the case how will be the old data be removed? $("#data1").empty().append(data) is true but that data1 is a script ?

Comment: `$("#data1").empty()` removes the old data.

Comment: I have create a temp fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/testaccount123/UtqyW/1 This is having the complete implantation of the HTML side. I could not keep the server code as it is difficult. But this is same as is code and this is having isue ewhen I keep the server..also you saod .empty will be called but you also said when there is a script eval() is called ..I am bit not clear with that statement

Comment: Fiddle doesn't work because the AJAX is going to a nonexistent URL. You can use their `/echo/json/` URL to get an AJAX response.

Comment: can I keep the response here ...I just used fiddle to show you the content "as is"

Comment: This is the 200 Ok payload; <script>
sampleListvar = [{"sampleinformation":"9111111",},{"sampleinformation":"654654654"},{"sampleinformation":"11"},{"sampleinformation":"12"},{"sampleinformation":"12"}]; $( "#sampleTemplate" ).tmpl( sampleListvar ).appendTo( "#sampleList" ); val1="page2";</script> ..same as in the one I have showed

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/UtqyW/6/. It doesn't do anything, because the returned script uses `$("#sampleTemplate")`, which doesn't exist in the fiddle. But it makes the AJAX call, clears the `#templatedata` DIV, tries to run the returned script, and gets the error because there's nothing to `appendTo()`.

Comment: Can I request you to a chat for 5min ? I dont see that getting cleared

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22015/discussion-between-barmar-and-the-learner)

Comment: Finally got a fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/UtqyW/13/. I forgot to capitalize the "L" in #sampleList, and the JSON I was sending said sampleinfo instead of sampleinformation, so it didn't match the template.

Comment: I was getting a question why did you keep $("#sampleList").html($("#sampleTemplate").tmpl(samplelistvar)). Actually sampleListvar is not part of the div-sampleList?. This part $("#sampleTemplate").tmpl(samplelistvar)).  I understand we are giving input to the template. I also understood we should not call append. I am but confused with the $("#sampleList") when you are trying to access the html to replace..

Comment: `$("#sampleList")` is the ID of the table body that should be updated with the result of filling in the template, `<tbody id="sampleList">`.

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
request.done(function(response) {
 alert('Loaded.');
 $('#data1').html(response);
 });
```

and the markup hsa a typo too to be more inline with good markup

```
<div="data1">
  <script> ...................</script>
</div>
 <!-- use / instead of \ to close tags-->
```

cheers

Comment: even then it is appending and not refreshing the content of the oage